# Bad practice in JDK's try-with-resources example?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I found this example in the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) documentation for Java:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

If the constructor for `BufferedReader` throws an exception, then the resources held by the `FileReader` won't be released. So isn't this a bad practice to write it like that instead of:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This constructor of BufferedReadet doesn't throw any exception, as far as I know.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer the second constructor does throw an  IllegalArgumentException though.

Comment: I know that. But the first one doesn't, according to its documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader-java.io.Reader-

Comment: My opinion is that even if the specific constructor doesn't throw an exception, I still wouldn't use this as a teaching example as it brushes over a potential problem related to the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, just gave it a quick try:

```java
public class MyFileReader extends FileReader {

    public MyFileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(fileName);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Closing MyFileReader");
        super.close();
    }

}

public class MyBufferedReader extends BufferedReader {

    public MyBufferedReader(Reader in) {
        super(in);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Closing MyBufferedReader");
        super.close();
    }

}

public String test(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new MyBufferedReader(new MyFileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

None of `MyFileReader` nor `MyBufferedReader` is closed... Good catch!

While with:

```java
public String test(String path) throws IOException {
    try (FileReader fr = new MyFileReader(path); BufferedReader br = new MyBufferedReader(fr)) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

`MyFileReader` is closed.

`BufferedReader` constructor can indeed throw exceptions, see [`BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz)` constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/BufferedReader.java?av=f#100) (although not when coming from [`BufferedReader(Reader in)` constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/BufferedReader.java?av=f#115), but the doc you linked should still alert on this possible issue IMHO).

Looks like you won the right to [raise an issue](http://bugreport.java.com/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are right.

The below example shows this behaviour - instance of `Internal` is never closed.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (External external = new External(new Internal())) {
        }
    }
}

class External implements Closeable {
    private Internal internal;
    public External(Internal internal) {
        this.internal = internal;
        throw new RuntimeException("boom");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("External.close()");
        internal.close();
    }
}

class Internal implements Closeable {
    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Internal.close()");
    }
}
```

Comment: However in the concrete case, the constructor of BufferedReader doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: Any checked exception.

Comment: Which exception does it throw exactly, and in which condition? The docunentation doesn't mention any exception to be thrown. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader-java.io.Reader-

Comment: @TobiasWeimer take the other constructor. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader-java.io.Reader-int-

Comment: That other constructor is not used in the example.